# Docker API /images/json always returns Containers:-1

Tags: docker, curl, dockerode

As stated in the API docs
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ImageList
an image should contain something like `"Containers": 2` but for me, all images returned by the api have `"Containers": -1` eventhough there are containers running that use the image
(checked with `docker ps -a`)

I'm running Docker Engine 18.09.2 with API version 1.39
I tested the image listing with the node package dockerode and with the curl commands

`sudo curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" http:/docker/images/json`

and

`sudo curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" http:/v1.39/images/json`

Comment: I can reproduce it, I got always -1 no matter what I do